# UPDATED: Ambient time context to help unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

The following test demonstrates the functionality of `Time` class which is supposed to be used instead of `DateTime.Now`. You could just read the static `Time.Now` property to get current UTC time. In case of unit testing though you could wrap the  code under test in a `using` statement in the form of `using(new Time(2019, 12, 31, 23, 59)) { ... }` and get this date and time consistently being returned till time context disposing.

```
[TestClass]
public class Time_Should
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Adjust()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(Time.Now > new DateTime(2020, 1, 1));
        using (new Time(2010, 1, 1))
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2010, 1, 1), Time.Now);
            using (new Time(2011, 1, 1))
                Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2011, 1, 1), Time.Now);

            Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2010, 1, 1), Time.Now);
        }
        Assert.IsTrue(Time.Now > new DateTime(2020, 1, 1));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: *For those who never tested ambient properties:*

Imagine that you have a business object depending on the current time:

```
class Job
{
     public decimal  DailyRate { get; set; } = 100;
     public DateTime Started { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
     public decimal Earned => (DateTime.Now - Started).TotalDays * DailyRate;
}
```

It is untestable. Using the class above would help with that:

```
class Job
{
       public decimal  DailyRate { get; set; } = 100;
       public DateTime Started { get; set; } = Time.Now;
       public decimal Earned => (Time.Now - Started).TotalDays * DailyRate;
}
```

Now you could test:

```
var job = new Job { Started = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1) };
using(new Time(2020, 1, 2))
      Assert.AreEqual(100m, job.Earned);
```

The library code:

```
public class Time : IDisposable
{
    static AsyncLocal<Time> Context { get; } = new AsyncLocal<Time>();

    public Time(int year, int month=1, int day=1, int hour=0, int minute=0, int second=0)
        : this(new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))
    {
    }

    public Time(DateTimeOffset constant)
    {
        Constant = constant;
        Parent = Context.Value;
        Context.Value = this;
    }

    Time Parent { get; }
    DateTimeOffset Constant { get; }

    public void Dispose() => 
        Context.Value = Parent;

    public static DateTimeOffset Now =>
        Context.Value?.Constant ?? DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
}
```

Comment: Why it is suggested to be closed?

Comment: It's closed (not by me, although I can understand why it happens) for lack of details. I suspect this can be helped by improving the description. Why did you write this code? What problem does it solve? You wrote the `Time` class I presume, but aren't there already in-built libraries for that? What is `Time.Now` fixing that `DateTime.Now` lacks? Is it a wrapper to consistency reasons?

Comment: @Mast Thanks for the clarification. I would though expect people to understand stuff they judge on :)